# install windows service through batch file in a particular directory and set login credentials

Tags: batch-file, windows-services, windows-installer

I have a windows service that I need to install in a userdefined directory instead of C: drive and set login credentials for it.
I am using the below code to install the service but it installs the service in C drive instead of E drive.

```
E:
cd \MyService
msiexec /i MyServiceInstall.msi /L E:\MyService\MyServiceInstallLog.txt /qn

sc config MyServiceInstall obj= uid password= pwd start= auto
rem net start MyService
```

I want to install the service at the location where the install file, MyService.msi, is present.

How do I go around this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't "get around" anything.  You create a proper MSI that uses the [ServiceInstall table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create the service.  The [ServiceInstall table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a UserName and Password column which is of type [Formatted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which means it can use properties like [USERNAME] and [PASSWORD].   Then you can simply say:

```
msiexec /i MyServiceInstall.msi INSTALLDIR=C:\INSTALLHERE USERNAME=bob PASSWORD=dontyouwhich
```

The only tricky part is that MSI doesn't grant the user account the SeLogonAsService right so a custom action will be needed to grant this prior to starting the service.